# Calculating difference between two rasters using ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, spatial-analyst, 3d-analyst

I'm using ESRI Desktop 10.2 with a spatial analyst extension. Can Spatial Analyst be used to calculate the difference between two water level raster files, or do you have to use 3D Analyst?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can use Spatial Analyst for this.

I'm not a Spatial Analyst expert, but I would look at the Raster Math tools to accomplish this - starting with the [Minus](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/minus.htm) tool.